# apt-get update fails inside Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, apt-get

When I try to build a simple docker image:

in Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
```

The output is:

```
$ sudo docker build --no-cache -t testbuild .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.471MB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> c090eaba6b94
Step 2/2 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 53d64603442f
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I tried:

1. build with different types of ubuntu images - e.g. ubuntu:16.04, 18.04,20.04 - and get a similar error '...Release' does not have a Release file.'
2. I completely removed and reinstalled docker from my system, inc all containers and repository, and rebooted, and get the same error

I previously built multiple docker images and everything worked fine. And now I get this error out of nowhere all the time.

Comment: Hi @GAD3R - yes it is docker-ce

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware and as far as I have checked (although im using a university network).

Comment: One thing I noted is that docker ubuntu `date` gives UTC time, while my local timezone is EST (UTC-5). I had tried changing this with various methods, but the same error still persists. e.g. [i found similar issue here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059217/getting-release-is-not-valid-yet-while-updating-ubuntu-docker-container)

Comment: Try adding `RUN echo "Your-TimeZone" > /etc/timezone` and `RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata` before `apt update`.

Comment: It gives `package tzdata is not installed` error. However to install `tzdata` I need to run `apt-get` to work. So it is like a chicken and egg.

Comment: to sync the clock I did this: 1. Build a 1 line container `FROM ubuntu` (i.e. no other commands) 2. run the container with copy of time from the local machine - `docker run -it --rm -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime testbuilt /bin/bash`. 3. Check time by running `date` (time is now corrected) 4. Try `apt-get update` from within the container - but the same error persists (`does not have a Release file`) - so I know the problem is not with time difference..

Comment: Maybe you need to set proxy in Dockerfile, like `ENV http_proxy=http://...` and `ENV https_proxy=http://...`

Comment: hi @Philippe how can i choose correct proxy?

Comment: Update - i tried to replicate on another computer which is on the same network (but has a completely independent version of docker setup) - same error. I also tried pulling much older versions of ubuntu from docker hub (e.g. from 2017) - same error. I then tried to pull centos and run equivalent command to `apt-get update` - `yum check-update` - i have an error also (although not sure if it is related). I then tried similar thing on fedora - `dnf check-update` - no error. And then on alpine - `apk update`. So it doesn't look like this is a proxy error?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I encountered this today, too. For me the "solution" was to use a newer image...

I was using `ubuntu:21.04` and getting this error, while `ubuntu:22.04` with no other changes did not give the error.